# executemany taking long and "killed" status when running the python code

Tags: python, oracle

```
myrows = []
for item in data:
    try:
        id= (item.get("data").get("id"))
    except AttributeError:
        id=''
    accounts = [(act["Account"]) for act in item.get("data", {}).get("mainAccounts", [])]
   
    rows=(id,accounts)
    myrows.extend(rows)

cursor.executemany(insert_statement,myrows)  
connection_target.commit()
```

the 'accounts' returns a list like ['0123','123','234','567']. Prior to this there was only value for account and there was no prob.  I'm trying to insert the values row by row in the oracle table like below

```
id account
1  0123
1  123
1  234
1  567
```

for some reason when i run the code ,the code gets stuck and i get "killed" status on terminal. Any ideas why executemany is taking long  or is there a better way to write this ?

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a table lock somewhere?  Did you need to commit/rollback in SQL*Plus (or other tool you are using)?

Answer (score 0):

You're not creating `myrows` correctly. It needs to have a separate element for each row you want to create. You're putting all the accounts into a nested list.

You can create the tuples with the `id` in them in the list comprehension.

```
myrows = []
for item in data:
    id = item.get("data", {}).get("id", '')
    accounts = [(id, act["Account"]) for act in item.get("data", {}).get("mainAccounts", [])]
   
    myrows.extend(accounts)
```

You can also use `get()` when setting `id` instead of `try/except`, just like you do in the `accounts` list comprehension.

Comment: thanks @Barmar. This worked. Appreciate your help.